# MongoDB service not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have recently upgraded my Ubuntu from 14.10 to 15.04. All features seems to be working fine except MongoDB. It is not controllable from service as we do normally in Ubuntu.

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

or

```
sudo service mongod start
```

I get this error message

> Failed to restart mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load:
>   No such file or directory.

But I have to start it manually each time I have to connect my application to MongoDB server using

```
sudo mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

So MongoDB is connected as long as that terminal is opened. I am using MongoDB in Ruby on Rails application using Mongoid adapater/ORM. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this depends that ubununtu 15.04 use systemd. Have you tried systemd `sudo systemctl start mongod.service`?  You can get a list of services with `systemctl`.

Answer (score 2):

Since your error is:

```
Failed to restart mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

This is pretty much saying that your startup path is not in the expected location or else the Ubuntu install has led to problems. See: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/

EDIT: Updated with link to what appears to be the answer, namely something is wrong with Ubuntu and mongo.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879231/upgrade-to-ubuntu-15-04-from-14-10-breaks-mongo-how-to-fix

Joel Parke has defined the problem and pointed to a ticket on the issue. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17742

That ticket reportedly explains how to "cleanly install current versions of mongodb on Ubuntu 15.04 by replacing the apt source."

Comment: I am using the default db path. It was all working fine before ubuntu update

Comment: @ShahzadTariq Answer from StackOverflow last week is likely the cause.  Updated post.

Comment: i did't get what u want to say

Comment: I updated the post with a reference to what appears to be your problem and gives an apparent solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the upstart service on Ubuntu. Mongo doesn't plan to support 15, and will instead support 16 LTS.

In the meantime, you can use the Mongo provided Debian sources.list instead of the Ubuntu one, and that will work on Ubuntu 15 (tested and proven to work on 15.04). Since you've already got the packages installed, you'll need to remove them first, add the new source, then reinstall.

```
sudo apt-get remove mongodb-org
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org 
service mongod status
```

Comment: Do you have a source for "Mongo doesn't plan to support 15, and will instead support 16 LTS"?  I'm not arguing the point, but I think it would add weight to your answer.